# Can someone please help me with the below scenario

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Powershell script with csv file of  query for (root) site collection, /Finace/ path only.

list of documents with the following columns in the CSV output file in the column order given.

- Column Display Value
- Internal Column Name

Write the output to a CSV filename with the name, StdsandRelatedDocuments.csv. Order by Path then ContentType, then Name. Include a Send Email instruction at the beginning and at the end of the run. Parameterize all appropriate elements.

The selection criteria is as follows:

1. From libraries in all sub webs in the /Finance/ path.
2. Where:

   - List Type = Library
   - ContentType = Finance Standards Documents or Finance Network Standards Documents or Document And
   - StdsDocStatus = Approved Note: for ContentType, you can also use = Document or Begins With “Finance”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a demo for your reference.

```
$siteUrl="http://sp:20971/test1"
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $siteUrl
$ctName1 = "Finance Standards Documents"
$ctName2 = "Finance Network Standards Documents"
$ctName3 = "Document"
$name="StdsDocStatus"
$file="c:\test\pp4.csv"

foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
    foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
        if ($list.BaseType -eq “DocumentLibrary”) {

           foreach ($ctype in $list.ContentTypes)  
             {  

                   if ($ctype.Name -eq $ctName1 -or $ctype.Name -eq $ctName2 -or $ctype.Name -eq $ctName3)  
                   {  


                      if($list.Items.Count -ne 0){

                     foreach($item in $list.items)

                     {

                       if($item[$name] -eq "Approved")
                        {       
                        $item.Fields | foreach { 
             $fieldValues = @{
            "Display Name" = $_.Title
            "Internal Name" = $_.InternalName
            "Value" = $item[$_.InternalName]
        }

         New-Object PSObject -Property $fieldValues | Select @("Display Name","Internal Name","Value")

                        }|Export-Csv -Path $file 



                     }

                         }


                    } 
             } 




        }
        }


        }
        }
```

[image]

More reference:
Get all column values from a SharePoint item using PowerShell.

http://get-spscripts.com/2010/09/get-all-column-values-from-sharepoint.html

Comment: If the reply is helpful to you, you could accept the answer.